# Check out a branch on the remote server with git

Tags: git

For my development workflow, when testing I often use a git repository on a remote machine then use the `receive.denyCurrentBranch updateInstead` setting to deploy my local changes to the remote server.

Is there an idiomatic way to check out a new branch on the remote machine.

For instance right now for a new feature:

```
git checkout -b new-feature
git push origin new-feature:new-feature
<Then I need to ssh to the remote server and git checkout new-feature>
```

My question is if there is a idiomatic way to avoid that step where I need to log into that server to change the working copy.

Comment: Post-receive git hook